# imageviews in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a rather complex layout with a ScrollView which contains a RelativeLayout. the RelativeLayout contains a TableLayout full of ImageViews. There are about 40 images. All of them are jpegs and all of them are exactly 200 pixels wide.

If I layout the table in three columns, it works fine.  But if I try to layout the table in two columns, then the first column displays the images fine, but in the second columns the images are "truncated" and the right most portion of the image is not visible.

For now the kludge workaround I came up was to create a "filler-image" which is a rectangle 50 pixels wide and 100 pixels tall. I stuck it in the 3rd column of the first row of the table, which makes this a three row tables, and scrunches the other two columns enough that they can both be read. But it seems like there should be a better way.

Here is a snippet of my xml (here including the filler image in the first row.

```
  <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/pls_table"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/pl_title"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pls_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="tsdetail2"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/abng_pl" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pls_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="tsdetail2"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/ag_supply_pl" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pls_fill"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/filler_image" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pls_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="tsdetail2"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/beard_implement_pl" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pls_4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="tsdetail2"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/j_r_tire_pl" />
        </TableRow>
```